# Google Maps Javascript API / Streetview FOV

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I was wondering if there was any way to change the field of view of a StreetviewPanorama object?

This is not documented anywhere but the Google Maps website does not seem to have the same FOV as the objects created via the API.

A couple of examples :

- Paris (Google Maps) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv1PN.jpg
- Paris (Google Maps API) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRMEc.jpg
- Italy (Google Maps) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iv4s.jpg
- Italy (Google Maps API) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu8Du.jpg

Everything looks way more spherical on Google Maps and much flatter with the API.

Both have the exact same coordinates and heading and zooming in doesn't help much.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a same problem like this.
Did you use Firefox too?

When I'm using Google Maps API on Chrome it's totally the same as the Google Maps.
Still can't find a way to solve it.

The fov should be the same as they mentioned in the documents.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview

So the problem will be the projection they used.

I just tried to change the user agent to cheating the API that I'm using chrome. And it works.

```
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function(){
    return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36' // customized user agent
});
```

But it turns out very slow when I try to drag the panorama.

Maybe that's why they're using a big flat image instead of a 3D spherical one.

---

2014/08/08 update

Good news to solve this problem.

I found a solution here in [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/FNP2INYAUpw/LurOZk0bX_EJ).

There's a undocumented attribute "mode" can be set in PanoramaOptions.

You can use 'html4', 'html5' and 'webgl'.

It will be no fish-eye effect if I set the mode to 'html5'.(But tourdash use 'webgl' instead)

The following shows the code snippet:

```
var panoramaOptions = {
        pano : panoId,
        pov: {
          heading: heading,
          pitch: pitch
        },
        enableCloseButton:false,
        addressControl:false,
        panControl:false,
        visible: true,
        clickToGo:false,
        addressControl:false,
        mode : "html5",
        zoomControlOptions:{
            position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
        }
    };
```

It works way much better than just set the user agent.

Comment: That's crazy. I did not expect Google Maps to have browser specific features like this (and yes I'm developing on Firefox). Your fix definitely works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Quick update : be careful with that user agent change. It can break some features on touch enabled devices.

Comment: Thanks, didn't noticed that. I'm still work on this. There must be some other way to fix this problem. At TourDash(the website) they can switch it alternatively on both browsers. That's really unbelievable.

Comment: Updated a better solution for this problem.