# Google Maps Javascript API v3 - different projection of the street view on firefox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API V3.
Everything works fine on chrome.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncC2Z.jpg

But we get a fish-eye effect on Firefox.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5o3z.jpg

It looks like they're using a totally different projection on each browser.

But the weird thing is that it works fine again on Firefox when I'm not using the API but the Google Maps directly.

Could someone deal with this problem?

---

Thanks! @try-catch-finally

The images are from the gogole maps api. A screenshot of two different browsers. The one of chrome is using sphere 3D effect, but the firefox one looks like a big flat image.

---

Okay, I think I just find a way to force the API to use the same way on both Chrome and Firefox.

And as @MrUpsidown said, I left my answer there.
But there's some problems need to be solved.
Hope you guys could move to that question and find a way out together.
I'll make this one to be closed someday.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please explain, what these images are showing? I mean: is the image data from you or provided by Google?

Comment: Identical question asked a few days back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498484/google-maps-javascript-api-streetview-fov not answered yet.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go helping him out to see if we have the same problems.