# Remove Google Street View Panorama Effect

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have a Google Street View that I have added using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3. You can see it [here](http://wahyanhong.digital-medium.co.uk/). Most of what the map does is fine. The only problem is that the Street View seems to be displaying the location in a weird spherical effect. I just want the street view to be the same as it is on [here](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.453479,-2.599875,3a,75y,226.84h,97.86t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1s-Y16zmvWWB0AAAGuq0wJtg!2e0!3e2) with just the straight image of the location without any panorama effect.

The code I have used is here:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDvvLfsqnDzgL4oe6HhKgVpmlosjKGME8E"></script>

<script>
function initialize() {
  var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(51.453484, -2.600000);
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: fenway,
    pov: {
      heading: 225,
      pitch: 20
    },
linksControl: false,
scrollwheel: false,
clickToGo: true
  };
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

    <div id="pano" style="width: 1920px; height: 560px;"></div>
```

Please tell me if I am missing something.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24565720/1238965) for an undocumented solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for answering my question. [The issue has now been solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498484/google-maps-javascript-api-streetview-fov/24565720#24565720). It turns out it is a Firefox-specific issue.

I'm now quoting the solution from user3109401's post from the link.

> There's a undocumented attribute "mode" can be set in PanoramaOptions.
>   You can use 'html4', 'html5' and 'webgl'.
>   It will be no fish-eye effect if I set the mode to 'html5'. (But tourdash uses 'webgl' instead)

```
var panoramaOptions = {
    pano : panoId,
    pov: {
      heading: heading,
      pitch: pitch
    },
    enableCloseButton:false,
    addressControl:false,
    panControl:false,
    visible: true,
    clickToGo:false,
    addressControl:false,
    mode : "html5",
    zoomControlOptions:{
        position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    }
};
```